# CLI could not contact EJBCA instance

Tags: jboss, pki, ejbca

I can't access to ejbca CLI althought the deploy build successfully, JBoss is up and running, FirewallD is not running and all Troubleshooting steps are treated mentioned here:

https://doc.primekey.com/ejbca/troubleshooting-guide/command-line-interface

/opt/ejbca/bin/ejbcaa.sh return

> Error: CLI could not contact EJBCA instance. Either your application server is not up and running, EJBCA has not been deployed successfully, or some firewall rule is blocking the CLI from the application server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most commonly due to that EJBCA has not been deployed correctly. Check the server.log file in WildFly/JBoss for errors.